# Assigning events in Javascript to appear in the HTML Inspector

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm having some trouble with events, i'm relatively new to all this so it may of already been answered and if so apologies!

I am trying to create an interactive GUI on a website, and at the moment, i have objects instantiating. when those objects are instantiated, their html and events are built and assigned entirely in Javascript. i then use JQuery UI to enhance some of those features, which works fine on chrome, but im trying to debug for firefox and am trying various things.

What i want to ask is:

Is there a way to assign an event to a specific element in javascript, and have it so that it appears in the HTML inspector as if you inline wrote that event in HTML?

`<div id="test" onmousdown=function(event)>`

why i ask is because, my events/functions that are working ok, are triggered this way.

At the moment im trying `addEventListener`, but it instantly listens to the button i clicked to instantiate the object and nothing else, and executes that function immediately.

Similarly, using the below didnt work either, it instantly fires the function whichever way i choose.

`Myobject.Onclick = function(event);`

The desired is result, is for the function to only execute when that specific element is clicked after it is instantiated.

```js
function newPostIt() {
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.id = "DraggableItem";
    newDiv.className = "PostIt PostItDiv";
    newDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", MyDrag);
    newDiv.addEventListener("mouseout", MyDragOut);
    var subjectText = document.createElement("div");
    subjectText.id = "tb1";
    subjectText.name = "tbSubject";
    subjectText.innerHTML = "Subject:";
    var messageBody = document.createElement("div");
    var message = document.createElement("span");
    message.id = "messagePI " + divCounterPostIts
    messageBody.id = "messageBodyPI";
    message.innerHTML = "this is just a test to see how the text wraps across the post it";
    var newDivEle = document.createElement("img");
    newDivEle.src = "Images/StickyNote.png";
    newDivEle.alt = "Nothing";
    newDivEle.className = "PostItImage " + divCounterPostIts;
    let newDivEle2 = document.createElement("img");
    newDivEle2.src = "Images/ExitIcon.png";
    newDivEle2.alt = "Nothing";
    newDivEle2.className = "ExitIcon " + divCounterPostIts;
    divCounterPostIts++;
    var Board = document.getElementById("Board");
    newDiv.appendChild(newDivEle);
    newDiv.appendChild(newDivEle2);
    newDiv.appendChild(subjectText);
    messageBody.appendChild(message);
    newDiv.appendChild(messageBody);
    Board.appendChild(newDiv);
    Draggables.push(newDiv);
    messageBody.onclick = ChangeText(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by adding parentheseses and passing an event in to the functions as they were set up in the listener.

```
newDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", MyDrag);
```

Even though MyDrag takes an event parameter, it works just as it is supposed to.

So, the bottom function ChangeText(event) is now added to an event listener like addEventListener(onclick, ChangeText) and it works as it should